# Cannot call value of non-function type 'HTTPURLResponse?'

Tags: swift3, alamofire

I'm trying to make Alamofire request by using this code block

```
    request = Alamofire.request(imageURL, method: .get)
                        .validate(contentType: ["image/*"])
                        .response(completionHandler: 

{ (request: URLRequest?, response: HTTPURLResponse?, data: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
```

but I'm getting the title of this question as a run time error.

How can I overcome this issue?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using response,data,error independently alamofire provides **data** which involve all of these parameters

Solution:

```
Alamofire.request(imageURL)
         .validate(contentType: ["image/*"])
         .response { data in
```

we can access error on data : ***data.error*** or response by ***data.response***